# Elasticsearch Nest 6 - Get index metadata

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Currently, I can retrieve the index mapping metadata from the following command on Kibana

`GET /[indexName]/_mapping/[documentType]`

Is there a way to do that on Elasticsearch Nest Client? If not, what other options would I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve it with

```
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var mappingResponse = client.GetMapping<MyDocument>();
```

which will send a request to

```
GET http://localhost:9200/default-index/_mapping/mydocument
```

In this case

- `index` will be `"default-index"`, the default index configured on Connection Settings
- `type` will be `"mydocument"`, inferred from the POCO type `MyDocument`

You can specify index and/or type explicitly if you want to

```
var mappingResponse = client.GetMapping<MyDocument>(m => m
    .Index("foo")
    .Type("bar")
);
```

which sends the following request

```
GET http://localhost:9200/foo/_mapping/bar
```

As well as target **all indices** and/or **all types**

```
var mappingResponse = client.GetMapping<MyDocument>(m => m
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
);
```

which sends the following request

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_mapping
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!  If you don't mind a follow up question, what would be the NEST syntax for the PUT command to insert_meta like this URL https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html?

Comment: `client.Map<MyDocument>(m => m.Meta(...));`